# WD 3TB Elements External HDD's sector size?

Tags: hard-drive

I am considering buying this hard drive. And I heard that Windows backup will not work with 4k sector size disk. Is that true? I want to know its physical sector size and logical sector size. I know I cannot change its physical sector size. Can I change its logical sector size?

Comment: Which version of windows? And chances are if its connected through USB its abstracted away anyway.

Comment: Where did you hear this exactly?